# Menu not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css

Coding a menu that appears when it reaches a device size of 1024 to replace a previous menu. Problem is that it is not aligning horizontally but menu option is stacking vertically above one another. Unfortunately the site is not live.

But here is the basic code, as it is a very simple menu layout at the moment

HTML:

```
<!--===================================================2nd Menu===================================================!-->
<div class="menu_scaled_wrapper">
    <div class="menu_scaled">
        <nav ul>
            <li><a href="index.html#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </nav>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*----------------------------Menu 2----------------------------*/
.menu_scaled_wrapper{
    display:none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    position:fixed;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5000;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    z-index:5000;
}
.menu_scaled{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.menu_scaled nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin:4% 50%;
}
.menu_scaled nav a{
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.menu_scaled nav a:hover {
    color:#900;
    transition:0.5s;
}
/*---------------------------- Menu Scaling ----------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .cbp-af-header{
        display:none;
    }
    .menu_scaled_wrapper{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .faderwrap{
        margin-top:80px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible from the above code to find the issue. the only thing I can refer to is You want to make the navbar 100% wide so why using display: inline-block? use display:block. If possible provide a fiddle demo.

Comment: you have a strange thing going on here: <nav ul>

Comment: To make ul-lists horizontal, use `li{ display: inline; }`

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that  `margin:4% 50%;` for your `.menu_scaled nav`?

Comment: @FarzadYZ http://jsfiddle.net/wefgjbdk/ here is a fiddle, with what it is actually doing.For user1120808, i did that based off of a previous menu, that had the code like that, may have to make some changes to get it correct. At chem1st question, that is just the positioning of the menu options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this.

```css
/*----------------------------Menu 2----------------------------*/
.menu_scaled_wrapper{
    display:none;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    position:fixed;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5000;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    z-index:5000;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 80px;
}

li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;
}
nav a:hover {
    color:#900;
    transition:0.5s;
}
/*---------------------------- Menu Scaling ----------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .cbp-af-header{
        display: none;
    }
    .menu_scaled_wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
    <!--===================================================2nd Menu===================================================!-->
<div class="menu_scaled_wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You can see a demo here http://codepen.io/johnweland/pen/EVvodq. I did this while trying to alter as little of your code as possible as I don't know what dependencies you have. The biggest problem I saw was your margin 4% 50% on the ul. This was breaking your layout keeping it from displaying inline.

Also if you don't need a lot of legacy support for browsers you could look into CSS3 flex-box which in my opinion is a godsend.As it makes it simple to align items in various ways. Which you can read about on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: perfect. Yea i saw that it was breaking through the margin, but couldnt get my head around it. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply `inline-block` style to each of the list elements, instead of one of their parents. This is because `display` is not an inherited attribute, so children elements will not display as `inline-block` just because their parents do.

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .cbp-af-header{
        display:none;
    }
    /* This selector is the change! It targets the individual list items */
    .menu_scaled_wrapper > .menu_scaled > ul > li {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .faderwrap{
        margin-top:80px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to the 'li' elements.